# Error Using Julia Genie - How to fix Genie load error?

Tags: julia

*PS.: I've tried to google it before post, but couldn't find anything useful.*

I'm using:

- Julia Version 1.4.1
- Genie v2.0.3

I am new to Julia language, just finished the "Introduction to julia" and started the "Get Started with Genie".
I had no problems/errors during the package installation, but when tried to use Genie, it showed the error below:

```
using Genie.Router

[ Info: Precompiling Genie [c43c736e-a2d1-11e8-161f-af95117fbd1e]
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: @invokelatest not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] #macroexpand#38 at ./expr.jl:108 [inlined]
 [2] macroexpand at ./expr.jl:107 [inlined]
 [3] docm(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::Any, ::Any, ::Bool) at ./docs/Docs.jl:523 (repeats 2 times)
 [4] @doc(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./boot.jl:463
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:377
 [6] include(::String) at /home/regis/.julia/packages/Genie/b0FAv/src/Genie.jl:4
 [7] top-level scope at /home/regis/.julia/packages/Genie/b0FAv/src/Genie.jl:42
 [8] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:377
 [9] top-level scope at none:2
 [10] eval at ./boot.jl:331 [inlined]
 [11] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:449
 [12] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /home/regis/.julia/packages/Genie/b0FAv/src/Commands.jl:26
in expression starting at /home/regis/.julia/packages/Genie/b0FAv/src/Commands.jl:11
in expression starting at /home/regis/.julia/packages/Genie/b0FAv/src/Commands.jl:11
in expression starting at /home/regis/.julia/packages/Genie/b0FAv/src/Genie.jl:42
ERROR: Failed to precompile Genie [c43c736e-a2d1-11e8-161f-af95117fbd1e] to /home/regis/.julia/compiled/v1.4/Genie/8eazC_3Abxq.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1272
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1029
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:927
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:922
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

update Julia to 1.6 and it should work fine. Also use Genie v3.3.0 or above. Genie is continuously involving(with new features and bug fixes) try to use latest tagged version

In `Project.toml` add a section

```
[compat]
Genie = "3.3.0"
```

and while in Pkg mode `]`

```
Pkg(1.6)> up # use up to update the package
```

More about compatibility: https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you're using Julia 1.4.1? Your problem might just resolve itself if you update to the latest stable version of Julia (1.6.2).

Comment: actually, I have installed the version available on Mint repositories. I will try to update to newest version and see if it works.